# Fixed width for a curved text in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, text

I have a canvas element, and a text is rendered in the canvas element, there is a slider outside, if you slide the text gets curved upside and downside, but I want the text to be a fixed width, right now the text gets expanded if you slide to both min max values, and gets shrinked at slider value zero. Also I need the straightened text on slider value zero. Hope you understand the problem.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("CanvasText");

    var ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.font = "30pt Arial";
    ctx1.textAlign = "center";
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var angle = Math.PI * 0.8;
    var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("sprd-slider");
    for(var i = 0; i < slider.length ; i++){
      slider[i].addEventListener('input',  function() { drawTextAlongArc(ctx1, "SHOYEB", centerX, centerY, this.value, angle) }, false)
    }


    function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {   
        var isPositive  = (Number(radius)>=0) ? true : false; 
        angle = isPositive ? -angle : angle;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
        context.save();
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
        context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);
        for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
          context.rotate(angle / str.length);
          context.save();
          context.translate(0, radius );
          var char = str[n];
          context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
          context.restore();
        }
        context.restore();
      }
```

```html
<input data-testid="text-angle" class="sprd-slider" type="range" min="-355" max="355" step="1" value="100" >
<canvas id="CanvasText" width="800" height="800" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "fixed width" maybe a couple of images can help... and the slider value zero that could be just an if statement

Comment: there is some text of width suppose 10 px, if I am making an arc or curve of the same text  I want the width be 10 px  not more or less, right now it gets shrinked and expands if you move the slider.